# como fijar el foco en un input y seleccionar el contenido de este

Tags: jquery, html5

Esta pregunta puede ser absurda pero no funciona codigos que he encontrado en busquedas

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
$(".nota").focusout(function(){
    var tx = $(this).val();
    if(tx.length == 2){
        alert("El valor ingresado no debe terminar en un punto");
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).select();
    }
});
```

El alert funciona bien, pero el input no sufre cambios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente tu código si funciona, lo que debes hacer es cambiar el `alert` por otra forma de mostrar el mensaje, además de que el `alert` ya no se usa te genera problemas con tu código por que al ejecutarse el `if` se muestra el `alert`, el `input` recupera su foco y selecciona su contenido pero al dar `click` en el botón aceptar estarías saliendo otra vez del `input` lo que volvería a repetir todo el proceso generando un `alert` que nunca se va a cerrar.

```js
$(".nota").focusout(function(event){
    var tx = $(this);
    if(tx.val().length == 2){
        $("#mensaje").html("El valor ingresado no debe terminar en un punto");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(tx).focus();
          $(tx).select();
        }, 10)
    }else{
        $("#mensaje").html("");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="nota">

<div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente. Ahora no entiendo por qué solo funciona en chrome y no en firefox

Comment: @Sagara acabo de editar el código para que te funcione tanto en chrome como en firefox, saludos

Comment: muchas gracias, funcionó

Comment: @Sagara te invito a que consideres marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores, saludos